# The type AndroidDriver is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <MobileElement>

Tags: eclipse, selenium, automation, appium

I have a simple code in order for automate my phone so it opens chrome by itself and open google.com but I get an error which I'm not sure how to fix.

I have all the updated Jars

```
package browser_tests;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;

public class ChromeTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Set the Desired Capabilities
        DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
        caps.setCapability("deviceName", "My Phone");
        caps.setCapability("udid", "77d1232f"); //Give Device ID of your mobile phone
        caps.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        caps.setCapability("platformVersion", "8.0");
        caps.setCapability("browserName", "Chrome");
        caps.setCapability("noReset", true);

        //Set ChromeDriver location
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\selenium_drivers\\chromedriver.exe");

        //Instantiate Appium Driver
        AndroidDriver<MobileElement> driver = null;
        try {
            driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), caps);

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        //Open URL in Chrome Browser
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    }
}
```

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The type AndroidDriver is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments 
    The type AndroidDriver is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments

```
at browser_tests.ChromeTest.main(ChromeTest.java:31)**
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the latest java_client 8.0, use java_client 7.6.0 and your problem will be gone

Comment: How people use java client 8 then?

Answer (score 0):

It's not an error to setup Android driver to return `MobileElement` from its `findElement` calls (see the [`AndroidDriver` class Javadoc in Appium's Github](https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/master/src/main/java/io/appium/java_client/android/AndroidDriver.java#L54)), so we can rule that out as the problem.

```
/**
 * Android driver implementation.
 *
 * @param <T> the required type of class which implement {@link org.openqa.selenium.WebElement}.
 *           Instances of the defined type will be returned via findElement* and findElements*.
 *           Warning (!!!). Allowed types:
 *           {@link org.openqa.selenium.WebElement}
 *           {@link org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement}
 *           {@link io.appium.java_client.MobileElement}
 *           {@link io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement}
 */
public class AndroidDriver<T extends WebElement>
```

But your issue is that the generic type shouldn't get put in the constructor call / when calling `new AndroidDriver`. See [line 34](https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/1991a8a0f9e4a3ff467dbb713cb5c51c8edc060f/src/test/java/io/appium/java_client/android/BaseAndroidTest.java#L34) and [line 54](https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/1991a8a0f9e4a3ff467dbb713cb5c51c8edc060f/src/test/java/io/appium/java_client/android/BaseAndroidTest.java#L54) of the `BaseAndroidTest` on Appium's Github for example usage.

```
public class BaseAndroidTest {
    // ...
    protected static AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver;

    @BeforeClass public static void beforeClass() {
        // ...
        driver = new AndroidDriver<>(service.getUrl(), capabilities);
}
```

Thus, to fix your issue, simply remove `MobileElement` from the `new AndroidDriver` constructor, but leave it in the declaration:

```
//Instantiate Appium Driver
AndroidDriver<MobileElement> driver;
try {
   driver = new AndroidDriver<>(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), caps);
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Your driver should instantiate.

Comment: I tried changing the code but I still get the error message:


`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 The type AndroidDriver is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <MobileElement>
 The type AndroidDriver is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <>

 at browser_tests.ChromeTest.main(ChromeTest.java:28)`

Comment: @BryanPerez can you please check out the code in the responses in this github issue? https://github.com/appium/java-client/issues/700 It's pretty much the same problem you are having, so try the code from TikhomirovSergey and it might help unblock you.

Answer (score 0):

change to java-client-7.2.0.jar to solve the problem
[go though this link](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client/7.2.0)